# Meaning of "we're a slenderer pair than you would make the half of" in Byron's "Don Juan"

Tags: meaning-in-context, poetry

From Byron's *Don Juan*:

> Here Lolah interposed -- "Mamma, you know
>        You don't sleep soundly, and I cannot bear
>   That anybody should disturb you so;
>        I'll take Juanna; **we're a slenderer pair
>
>   Than you would make the half of**; -- don't say no;
>        And I of your young charge will take due care."
>   But here Katinka interfered, and said,
>   "She also had compassion and a bed.

What is the meaning of **we're a slenderer pair than you would make the half of**?

When we lie together, we take up less than 50% of your width?

Comment: I don't know why you didn't post this in [literature.se]. In a hurry?

Comment: @Mick - because a question about meaning-in-context would be off-topic in Literature

Comment: I didn't realise that.

Comment: @Mick - well, maybe not off-topic, but I'm never sure with questions of this kind.. I've been told there once already to ask a question here instead.

Comment: I think that I can guess the reason for that.

Comment: CowperKettle, @Mick - a question about the meaning in context would definitely be on topic for us over at [literature.se]. (Source: I'm a Literature.SE mod.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the context, I would say that Lolah is suggesting that she share her bed with Juanna, rather than her mother, since Lolah and Juanna together would take up less room than Lolah and her mother. Whether this is really for Lolah's benefit, rather than her mother's, is open to interpretation.

So, you are correct (I think), although it may be an exaggeration.

Comment: So "Lolah + Juanna" is less than 50% of the width of "Momma + Juanna". I see. Thank you!

Comment: It's possibly an exaggeration.

Comment: @CowperKettle No you still have it wrong. The comparison is between the total space taken by each pair. The *half of* bit isn't about the totals, it's just saying that Momma would be one half of that pair. Ie., the pair that you would be half of.

Comment: @PhilSweet - thank you! Now at last I understand this.